# Inline CSS in JSP

Tags: css, jsp, email

I'm designing email, and we're using JSP for HTML generation. To maximize compatibility with various clients, inline CSS should be used; however, it's very hard to maintain.

Is there any "proper" way of inlining styles in JSP from head or external css file except for using other preprocessors (i.e. tasks for Gulp or Grunt)?

Answer (score 1):

if you use CSS linked file then there is a chance that some email clients might block them.

The most reliable way to include CSS in an HTML email is to use inline styles. They aren't pretty, but few email clients ignore them.